# iPhone Database & Server Database - iPhone updates only modifications

Tags: iphone, sql-server, xcode, sqlite

I have some query. First of all let's have an iPhone application flow which a normal application has. ( Content based application )

- Application launches & checks for the network availability
- If network is available - iPhone downloads the data using web services or APIs
- We can store these response ( web service response / api response ) into a *.plist file.
- When we need to update the data, again web service is called & again entire data is stored *.plist file.
- Now, assume that - I have a table 'eBooks' on Server & It has more than 500 entries.
- Calling a API/web service will give response of 500 records.
- OK - first time it is ok to wait for all response ( we might use LIBXML2 for chunks )
- But what if when we frequently download this using web service.

Here there are two disadvantages

- Wifi unnecessary usage
- iPhone CPU overhead
- Server CPU overhead.

Are you getting me?

Assume that there is no change on server why iPhone need to call API again. Means there are no change in entries & entries are 500 as it is then why to download it again?

Let me clarify again - the problem.

Assume that

- an application has a Server + database = Customers ( 500 records currently )
- there are 5 iPhone which retrieves this data
- all iPhones have downloaded 500 records offline
- Now, server has added a new record 501
- iPhone must download only 1 record not 501 at all.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a timestamp to each of the entries. This timestamp is updated every time a change, addition or deletion is made on the server side.

When doing a query, you supply a field indicating the latest timestamp known to the client. For the first query, this would be something like Epoch. For subsequent queries it would be the last known update.

The server would then have to filter the entries, so it only returns those entries that have changed since the provided timestamp.

Comment: @Claus Broch - idea is great - would you please give some more brief ?

Comment: @Claus Broch - so, iPhone will give timestap while calling web service to server & server will check for each record of database for timestamp. serverTimeStamp==iPhoneTimeStamp - for each record. assume there are 500 iPhone application users. What will happen to server ?

Comment: I presume you ave the data in some sort of database, so it would simply be a matter of constructing a SQL statement that does the filtering (e.g. something similar to "SELECT * from TABLE mydata WHERE timestamp >= querystamp") . Probably the server will be less loaded with filtering than it would by serving full content every time.
This is however only a rough guestimate, you mileage may vary.

Comment: But what about deleted records ? assume 401 & 302 records are deleted - what to do in this case ?

Comment: For "deleted" records you actually don't delete them, but instead you mark them as deleted in the database. You will need to design your tables in the database, so this only takes up space for the fields used for change management. The actually data could then be located in different tables.

Comment: Ok ! I got the answer - very great support like a sales team. Thank you very much. +1 +accepted.

Comment: Actually - I am getting message - "you last voted on this answer
2 hours ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited". will u please edit your question, so that I can up vote you.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily implement paging on your server app to let your clients limit the number of entries retrieved. You can also implement some kind of unique identifier that you can cache on the iPhone client and then when you request an update you send the unique identifier of the last item you have cached. When your server sends the response, it should only serve items newer than the last item you have cached.

Comment: Why is wifi required for paging?